# Superstar Saga + Bowser's Minions - Ludwig's first attack

Tags: ml-superstar-saga-bowsers-minions

Ludwig seems to start the fight always with the same attack. The blue fire that you can hit with hammers isn't too big of a deal, but rather the orb that slowly descends on you. You can't hit it and it does nearly 1000 damage on level 39. How big level is the game expecting?

Comment: I changed your title and tag to specify you're playing the "+ Bowser's Minions" remake, since the fight is very different from what you describe in the original game.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* hit the giant slow-descending orb. In fact, you *must*. The only way to win the fight is to hammer back the giant orb.